# How do I assign an Interceptor AFTER a SessionFactory has been created?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

We have a code base that uses the Hibernate implementation of JPA but that has to date only utilized the basic facilities of JPA.  In particular that means we have used EntityManager instead of SessionBuilder.  This approach was taken because (until now) we only needed the base JPA facilities and saw no benefit to using Hibernate constructs.  However, we now need the facilities that a Hibernate Interceptor can provide and are looking for some way to implement this.

We see how to obtain the Session and SessionFactory from an existing EntityManager but cannot see how to "add" an Interceptor to an existing Session(Builder).  We can find numerous examples showing how to configure a SessionFactory so that upon construction of the SessionFactory it will start up with an Interceptor but how can an Interceptor be added if (through the creation of an EntiryManager) the SessionFactor already exists?

Thank you.

09/09/14  EDIT:
Per the link (http://nsinfra.blogspot.com/2013/10/audit-logging-using-hibernate.html) supplied by AVolpe I learned about the persistence.xml !  I added  but upon deployment to JBoss 7 I get:
**[PersistenceUnit: PU] Unable to find interceptor class: com.MyCom.model.HibernateInterceptor.**

Here's HibernateInterceptor:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
HibernateInterceptor() {}
... the required overrides ...
}
```

Any idea why the class HibernateInterceptor is not being found?

09/11/14 Edit: 
No, no Spring here.

I have altered my approach a bit, think there is some progress but now have an error.  Here are the particulars:

To "register" an Interceptor after the Session has started I now do this:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName=UtilitiesModel.JPA_PERSISTENCE_UNIT)   
private EntityManager em;   
...    
SessionFactory sessionFactory = entityManager.unwrap(org.hibernate.Session.class).getSessionFactory();  
Session session = sessionFactory.withOptions().interceptor(new MyInterceptor()).openSession();
```

This does not generate any errors at compile or deployment time.

It is my understanding that I also need to "register" the Interceptor in persistence.xml and here is how that is done:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.interceptor." value="com.MyCom.model.HibernateInterceptor." />
```

Finally, here is HibernateInterceptor:

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
HibernateInterceptor() {}

@Override
public void onDelete(...

...
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error when I deploy (out of Eclipse - Kepler) to JBoss 7:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PU] Unable to find hibernate.ejb.interceptor: com.MyCom.model.HibernateInterceptor.
```

Do I need to annotate HibernateInterceptor in some fashion?  Can you see what is wrong here?

Comment: Check this http://nsinfra.blogspot.com/2013/10/audit-logging-using-hibernate.html (see the hibernate.ejb.interceptor part). Also if you specify your use case we can help you with alternatives.

Comment: Hi AVolpe,

Thanks for the link; please see the addition to my original post.  Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: You are using Spring?

Comment: Hi AVolpe, Please see my latest addition to my original post. Again, thanks very much for the help.